# How to pass struct to system call, then copy kernel data to that struct

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel

I am trying to pass a struct pointer to a custom system call and then copy the kernel data to the user space.

My main problem is that I have trouble debugging where the problem is. That can be explained by the fact that I am fairly new to the C programming language and while also modifying the kernel source.

So far, I've tried the following:

The struct (just a simplified version of the actual one that the user space program uses (mystruct.h)):

```
struct mystruct {
    pid_t pid;
        //...
};
```

My custom call itself:

```
struct mystruct {
    pid_t pid;
        //...
};

asmlinkage long sys_mysyscall(struct mystruct __user *userStructPtr){
    struct mystruct kernelData;

    if(!userStructPtr){
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    //Insert kernel data into struct
    kernelData.pid = current->pid;
    //...

    //Copy kernelData to userStructPtr (user space)
    if(copy_to_user(userStructPtr, &kernelData, sizeof(kernelData))){
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And finally my program that tests it:

```
int main (void) {
    struct mystruct userStruct;
    printf("%ld\n", syscall(sys_mysyscall, &userStruct));
    printf("PID: %d\n", userStruct.pid);
        return 0;
}
```

I tried debugging as best as I can. As such, I know I can successfully call my custom system call (thanks to printk) but it returns -1. Plus, I know that the data that I'm inserting into kernelData is good (eg: current->pid yields the right PID). The output of my test program isn't the same as the data inserted into kernelData.

As so, I am unable to find why copy_to_user fails.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am unable to find why copy_to_user fails." - Well, this seems to be a **primary** problem: if copying into user space struct fails, then the application definitely cannot read intended value of the field. Have you tried to print a value of the `userStructPtr` pointer inside your `sys_mysyscall` function? Is it the same as address of `userStruct` you pass from the application?

Comment: Using printf from my application, I have 0x7ffefed8be60 as the pointer address. Meanwhile, using printk from the syscall, the address is 000000005203076a. Is it me or the address format (printf("%p") in the user space is different from the one in the kernel space (printk("%p"))?